# Android : remote app id does not match stored id (Only on Google Play)

Tags: android, facebook

I've got a problem with my application on Google Play! I have a Facebook connection and it works fine when I test in Eclipse, but when I distribute it on Google, I get this error message: "remote app id does not match stored id". Any ideas?

Comment: When you test in Eclipse, your APK gets signed with a debug certificate. WHen you publish the APK on Google Play, it must be signed with a certificate you've created (which cannot be the debug certificate). I would guess your facebook id is tied to the signing certificate and this you will need one for your release certificate.

Comment: Eclipse sign app with debug key ... and if you export your app it Is signed with other key.... use the second one to generate facebook app id

Comment: OK thanks. Do you know how can I get this key ?

Comment: Do you solve you issue ? I am in the exactly same situation !! Google n'aime pas les français ou quoi ^^

Comment: Yes I've solve it ! With the solution in the bottom of the page ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an article explaining how to sign your Android app. http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

There is information there on how to generate your keys as well as how to use them within Eclipse.

Here is the example from that page on how to generate a private key:

```
$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore
-alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Make sure you read the whole page, there is lots of good information there.

Comment: My problem is with Facebook key, not APK publishing... :/

Comment: You have the register the certificate used to publish the apk with Facebook

Answer (score 0):

I've entered this command :

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin>keytool -exportcert -alias MYALIAS -ke
ystore "C:\xxxxx\xxxxx.keystore" | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" sha1 -bi
nary | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" base64

The alias is correct, the path to...
I don't understand why the key is steel incorrect...

Thanks for your help...